# Using * in regular expression in the action name of struts2

Tags: regex, struts2, action-mapping

My url may or may not have a certain parameter and I set the action class for such a url as follows :

```
<action name="{paramOne}/{paramTwo:myparam*}/details" 
     class="myaction"  
     method="execute"> 
     <result name="success">/mypage.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

So the url `something/myparam/details` is working but when i try to invoke `something/details` (which according to `struts.xml` should work). It shows that there is not action class mapped.

Comment: You can use many action mappings to the same class.

Comment: I know that. But i want to achieve this in a single action mapping

Answer (score 0):

your code '*' only can match between "{paramOne}/" and "/details"
so you must have something between "{paramOne}/" and "/details"

Comment: Is there any other way, i can achieve the above? both something/myparam/details and something/details should map to the same action class (defining a single action name)

Comment: you can use "*/details"

Answer (score 0):

You want to route different URI patterns to the same action, this is exactly the case action mapping is made for.
I think the best solution is to write two separate statements.

If you don't want to repeat the "code" inside the `<action>` tag you can `chain` it (it's a kind of internal redirect, a kind of aliasing)

```
<action name="secondpattern" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport">
    <result type="chain">firstpattern</result>
</action>
```

https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html

Comment: Using `chain` is discouraged. And not sure how this solves OP problem.

Comment: I woudn't say it is discouraged, rather say "use it with wisdom and parsimony" if you don't want to end up with a spaghetti chain of actions. I found it useful dealing with language-specific patterns: for example you map the pattern `*/restaurant` and then you want to create language _aliases_ `*/restaurante` and `*/ristorante`: the "logic" (parameters, interceptor, results, etc) is written only in the first mapping, the others are `chain` to the first.

Comment: It doesn't even seem related to my problem

Comment: @fustaki With the caveat that this could be handled w/ regexes, interceptors (for even better I18N of routing), etc. Chaining really isn't recommended; there's almost always a better way.